# Mistakenly changed 'mark as active drive' to D, now cannot boot, says 'bootmgr is missing' (windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, bootmgr

I was trying to restore the laptop ( HP dv6 pavillion) and mistakenly set active drive to D. Now cannot boot the windows. I do not have windows installation disk. I could not download new iso for windows as last few digits of my key have faded.
I found articles online only give the information regarding the fixing the drive by use of installation disk. 
Is there a fix to it?

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options:

1) Try repairing your boot drive using a Linux live CD (you can also install grub, which will probably do everything for you)

2) Get a Windows DVD (I assume you run Windows 7 and so you are unable to get an ISO) from someone and repair using it.

3) Use a solution like boot-repair-disk:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/

**This one is for everyone having a worn out CoA (Certificate of Authorization). Manufacturers or Microsoft will NEVER help you get back your CoA.**

4) Take a soft pencil (preferably 4B or 6B) and slowly, gently rub it on the CoA label which has the key. Since the key is engraved, it slowly shows up. If you get the CoA a bit dirty, gently rub it with your finger and keep trying. DON'T touch the label with any kind of cleaning solution or water. Using this method, I have recovered a completely invisible CoA!

Comment: hey @Radial I got ubuntu usb. But I am really noob at it. can you help me with a guide for this?

Comment: http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd